# Order Updated At Date same as Created At

Tags: magento2, event-observer, plugin

I am using the after plugin for the Place method following this link https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/create-plugin-after-place-order-action-checkout-magento-2/

But I get the order updated at the date time same as created at date time. I am not using the sales_order_place_after event as it doesn't have created at an updated value.

Which is the right event or method(for plugin) to get created and updated at the date after the order is placed using rest API and frontend?

Answer (score 0):

You can observe the event sales_model_service_quote_submit_before and set the created_at field there.
This event is dispatched before the order is persisted in the DB and you get as a parameter the order object.
But this event gets dispatched for every order.

```
 namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

class QuoteSubmitBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        if ($quote && $order) {
            $order->setCreatedAt(your custom date here);
            $order->setUpdatedAt(your custom date here);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply @mohith. But I still get updated_at time same as created_at time. I didn't get what you mean by "set the created_at field there".

Comment: @VishwanathKharabe by using the above event we can set the created_at and updated_at, kindly check the code snippet and modify it according to your need